# PHP strip string

Tags: php, string

```
$var = 'Click on this <a href="#">link</a>. (goes to heaven) (and then somewhere else)';
```

How to get the text, which is placed between first brackets?

Throw its value to `$extra`

In this example `$extra = 'goes to heaven'`

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
preg_match("/\\((.+?)\\)/", $var, $matches);
$extra = $matches[1];
```

This is strictly true for the example you provided. If you are parsing arbitrary HTML, you'll have to use [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/DOMDocument) or similar instead.